# rspec expectation syntax with validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

New to rspec, and wondering how to write an expectation for validates_associated.

#### post.rb

```
class Post
  validates_associated :user
end
```

#### post_spec.rb

```
it 'must belong to a user' do
  post = build(:post, user: nil)
  expect(post).to have(1).errors_on(:user)
end
```

However this doesn't work, nor does checking for error_on(:user_id)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Post
  validates_associated :user
end

class User
  validates :name, presence:true
end
```

Validates associated practically means with example

```
post = Post.find 1

post.title = "something"
post.user.name =  nil

post.save => false
```

It returns false as associated user is not valid because
user's name is not present.

To test it, you should:

```
it 'validates associated user' do
  post = build(:post)
  post.user.build(:name => nil)
  post.save.should == false
  post.user.errors.should == {:name => [name must be present]} // something like this
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to use RSpec, particularly in light of the recent transition from the `should` to `expect` approach. In this answer, I'll try to respond to why your test isn't working as is, *assuming* that build called with those particular arguments would indeed raise the error you say it should. In other words, I'll try to respond to the form of your test.

First, I'm not sure what you intended with your statement `post = build(...)`.  If you intended to actually *execute* the build method at that point and you expect the execution of build to fail, that's going to cause your test to fail. To test the raising of an error, you need to pass the code which is going to raise the error to RSpec and let RSpec invoke it. In general, you want to set expectations *before* executing the code under test.

If you expected `post = build(...)` to be defining `post` as a function to invoke build, that's not the right syntax. If you wanted to use this approach, you'd have to say `post = lambda {build(...)}`. That would allow the `expect` method to execute `post` and examine what errors are raised by it.

Alternatively, you can pass a block directly to expect, as in:

`expect{build(...)}.to ...`

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-error for more examples.